# @Nonnull behavior different for Eclipse Juno and Kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsr305

I'm running into a rather odd scenario that I've so far managed to pinpoint to differing versions of Eclipse. I'm wondering if someone could tell me what exactly the issue is (Juno doesn't support, it, Kepler provides better support, etc). I'm using jsr305 for annotations.

I have the following example code to replicate the behavior.

```
@Nonnull
String test = null;
```

This shouldn't work as I've explicitly said using annotations that test should not be null. It catches it in Kepler, but in Juno it doesn't. All the settings are the same, is this just a case of version incompatibility with jsr305?

Comment: Are you using the same version of jsr305 in both environments?  What is that version?

Comment: Yes, same version, unfortunately I'm not sure. The manifest file does not include the version.

Comment: I can only guess that the compiler options in the Java Compiler preferences are either different or set differently

Answer (score 0):

Juno did not support marking fields as `@Nullable` but Kepler does.
See these interesting posts:

- Potential fix: [Is there a good Eclipse plugin for checking @Nonnull and @Nullable annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659637/is-there-a-good-eclipse-plugin-for-checking-nonnull-and-nullable-annotations)
- Related article: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2013/09/09/nullable-in-kepler.html

I prefer to stick with FindBugs Maven plugin as I do not depend on the IDE and can enforce policies at build time. I mainly use these annotations:

```
import javax.annotation.CheckForNull;
import javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
```

I should probably have a look at IDE support too but that would only be an 'extra'.